# how to use geocoder.getFromLocation in android Java for API level 33

Tags: java, android

```java
public String getCityName(double longitude, double latitude) {
    String cityName = "Not Found";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    try {

        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 3);

        for (Address adr : addresses) {
            if (adr != null) {
                String city = adr.getLocality();
                if (city != null && !city.equals("")) {
                    cityName = city;
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "CITY NOT FOUND");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "USER CITY NOT FOUND...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Geocoder", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return cityName;
}
```

So this is my code to get the city name. I'm stuck at `geocoder.getFromLocation()`. It tells me that this method was deprecated in API level 33 and tells me to use `getFromLocation(double, double, int, android.location.Geocoder.GeocodeListener)` instead. Please help me solve this I'm still new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You can still use this depreceted method because the deprecation reason tells that new method fix thread blocking issues.

> Use getFromLocation(double, double, int, Geocoder.GeocodeListener) instead to avoid blocking a thread waiting for results.

So if you ensure that operation is runnig on background thread it still should work.

And if you want to use this new method for devices on api 33 and above you should make if statement that checks actual SDK version like:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
```

and then:

```
    geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 3, addresses -> {
        // Your logic with addresses here
        // *this method will be invoke when Geocoder resolves location 
    });
```